# Disable analzer in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

So quick question regarding WSO2 API manager and BAM from what I can tell Bam saves the basic requests to the API manager to the DB and the Publisher then reads from the DB when displaying the stats. At what point in the analyzer part of BAM in action ie Casandra and Hadoop. Or does that just get used if I write my own hive queries?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you integrate WSO2 BAM with API Manager for Analytics following happens.

1. API Manager publishers data using thrift for BAM.
2. There are hive scripts which is included in the toolbox. There are scheduled and when they are running summarized data will be inserted into the databases.